# Can we express QFT in R^8 where the spacetime can be embedded in?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, quantum-gravity

A smooth, 4-dimensional manifold can be embedded in $R^8$. Isn't it a natural selection of space for QFT when we try to extend QFT with gravity?

Comment: Why would an embedding matter, at all? It's an arbitrary process that introduces additional degrees of freedom and now you have to explain those away, otherwise they should give rise to gauge fields, shouldn't they?